# Workaround for inability to have multiple inheritance in Java

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

I know that you cannot extend multiple classes in Java. So, I need help solving this problem.

I have these classes:

```
abstract class ObjWithID {
    final int id;

    public ObjWithID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

abstract class ObjWithIDActivity extends ObjWithID {

    public ObjWithIDActivity(int id) {
        super(id);
    }

    boolean active;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}

abstract class ObjWithIDPriority extends ObjWithID {

    public ObjWithIDPriority(int id) {
        super(id);
    }

    int priority;

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

Some of my classes (most of them) need both `activity` and `priority`. So, in a perfect world, I would write this:

```
class Employee extends ObjWithIDPriority, ObjWithIDActivity implements Comparable<Header> {

    public Employee(int id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Header o) {
        return Integer.compare(o.priority, priority);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can't extend multiple classes.

In my current code, I simply created a third class:

```
abstract class ObjWithIDActivityPriority extends ObjWithID {

    public ObjWithIDActivityPriority(int id) {
        super(id);
    }

    boolean active;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    int priority;

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

But, this is causing me to have to write a lot more code because I if I create a method that accepts an `ObjectWithIDActivity` as a parameter, I need to duplicate it for `ObjWithIDActivityPriority`s.

I've tried the multiple inheritance workaround of using `interface`s, but that causes problems because I am using fields `int id`, `int priority`, and `boolean active` and getters/setters for those fields. Also, interfaces can't have constructors.

So, what is the best way to implement this? Is the third class the only option??

Comment: "Prefer composition over inheritance". Unfortunately, not without boilerplate.

Comment: Use Java 8! Multiple Inheritance from interfaces! :D

Comment: @DirkyJerky doesn't work in this case since you can't have instance variables.

Comment: Since you could argue that any activity must have a priority, why not just have ObjWithIDActivity extend ObjWithIDPriority?

Comment: Java 8 is not an option until Oracle pushes it via the auto-updater or, at least, until it appears on this site: http://www.java.com/en/download/windows_xpi.jsp?locale=en (because I can't ask end-users to download it through the Oracle site).

Comment: Another note: I **very** strongly recommend that you use an enum instead of just an integer for the priority. You don't want to wind up searching your project for hard-coded `3`s down the road because someone wants to tweak the priorities (and someone will--that I guarantee).

Comment: I don't think there's enough information for a solution.  The answer to a question like this depends on the overall design needs of the entire application; you can't simply reduce it to a small test case and ask "What's the answer?".  In this case, I don't see why you need `ObjectWithIDActivity` or `ObjectWithIDPriority` abstract classes, as opposed to separate `Activity` or `Priority` classes that would become instance fields in some objects.  It looks like a "design smell".  Maybe there are good reasons, but I can't tell from a small example.

Comment: @DirkyJerky Multiple inheritance from interfaces has been around a lot longer than Java 8.  Java 8 didn't add anything that would help with this problem at all (interfaces can now have default methods and static methods, which are irrelevant to this question).

Answer (score 0):

Not a viable answer because the asker says he can't use Java 8, but I thought I'd post this because it's interesting. It's an abomination to be sure, but it does at first glance seem to circumvent Java's multiple inheritance restriction. Any comments?

```
public interface ObjWithID {
    public static final Map<ObjWithID, Integer> idMap = new HashMap<>();
    default public int getId() {
        return idMap.get(this);
    }
}


public interface ObjWithIDActivity extends ObjWithID {
    public static final Map<ObjWithIDActivity, Boolean> activeMap = new HashMap<>();
    default public boolean isActive() {
        return activeMap.get(this);
    }
    default public void setActive(boolean active) {
        activeMap.put(this, active);
    }
}


public interface ObjWithIDPriority extends ObjWithID {
    public static final Map<ObjWithIDPriority, Integer> priorityMap = new HashMap<>();
    default public int getPriority() {
        return priorityMap.get(this);
    }
    default public void setPriority(int priority) {
        priorityMap.put(this, priority);
    }
}


public class NewClass implements ObjWithIDActivity, ObjWithIDPriority {
    public void foo() {
        int id = getId();
        int priority = getPriority();
        boolean active = isActive();
    }
}
```

Good luck with the diamond pattern!

Comment: One issue is that it would break automatic garbage collection of the parent interfaces, since the maps contain references to them. Replacing `HashMap` with `WeakHashMap` would work.

Answer (score 0):

My take with composition:

```
public interface IDItf {
    abstract int getId();
    abstract void setId(int id);
}
class IDSupport implements IDItf {
    int id;

    public IDSupport(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
public interface PriorityItf {
    abstract int getPriority();
    abstract void setPriority(int priority);
}

... (PrioritySupport class)

public interface ActivityItf {
    abstract boolean isActive();
    abstract void setActive(boolean active);
}

... (ActivitySupport class)

class Employee implements IDItf, PriorityItf, ActivityItf, Comparable<Header> {
    private IDSupport idSupport;
    private PrioritySupport prioritySupport;
    private ActivitySupport activitySupport;

    public Employee(int id) {
        super();
        idSupport = new IDSupport(id);
        prioritySupport = new PrioritySupport(0);
        activitySupport = new ActivitySupport(false);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Header o) {
        return Integer.compare(o.prioritySupport.getPriority(), prioritySupport.getPriority());
    }

    // Delegate methods (create them with Eclipse or other IDE's features)
    public int getId() {
        return idSupport.getId();
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        idSupport.setId(id);
    }
    ...
}
```

The ...Support classes are rather trivial, but if they require a little more logic, they make more sense. The fields in class `Employee` could use a `final` keyword.

I found the composition helpful in the past. Having the boilerplate code doesn't feel good initially. However, the delegate methods can be generated by the IDE. The Support classes could also mostly be generated (create the field, let the IDE create the constructor and the getters/setters). The downside may be a big slump of generated code which still has to be maintained. However, I prefer simpler code in the long run, even it is boring to read. In the past 25 years more than once I looked at my code from some time ago and wondered what I was thinking. Sometimes even comments don't help if one didn't document the crucial hint which was obvious back then but isn't now.

Answer (score 0):

Java way is to use interfaces, `Activable` and `Priorisable` and to put implementation including state in all implementing classes.

Comparable here should be inherited by `Priorisable`.

If you really want to factorize state declaration (but imho there is no need to) you could hide your model classe behind some interface (`Employee` implemented by `EmployeeImpl`) and make the model implementation classes extends a modelBase POJO exposing all possible attributes (active, priority...). When manipulating the model classes through  their interfaces only the usable method will be exposed.

Comment: if you want powerful and safe multi-inheritance go with scala traits ;) (would run perfectly in the JVM too)